# Fazer um loop com uma lista do GetPrivateProfileSection C++

Tags: c++

estou com uma dúvida, sou iniciante. Queria listar todos nomes das chaves de um arquivo ini, mas só o nome das chaves e fazer um loop do primeiro item ao ultimo.

```
char lista[255];
GetPrivateProfileSection("ITENS",lista,255, ".\\arquivo.ini");
ostringstream os;
os << listando;
   for(int a = 0; a < lista; a=a+1){
os << lista[a];
}
```

Quero as chaves pedido1, pedido2, pedido3...

Arquivo.ini

```
[ITENS]
pedido1 = 3552
pedido2 = 2208
pedido3 = 2066
pedido4 = 5787
pedido5 = 2966
pedido6 = 8889
```

Comment: Dica rápida, no incremento faça a++ pois será melhor que a=a+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve receber em lista, algo como: `"pedido1 = 3552\0pedido2 = 2208\0pedido3 = 2066\0\0"` <sup>[1](https://vcpptips.wordpress.com/tag/getprivateprofilesection/)</sup> <sup>[2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getprivateprofilesection)</sup>

```
for(const char *resultado=lista; strlen(resultado); resultado+=strlen(resultado)+1)
    os << std::string(resultado, (int)(strchr(resultado, '=') - resultado));
```

Comment: E para ler as seções do .ini? GetPrivateProfileString lê um valor em string do arquivo .ini. E como lê uma seção inteira como lista, nas só o nome?