# Como ler todas chaves de uma seção de um arquivo .ini? C++

Tags: c++

Alguém pode me ajudar com essa dúvida? Eu queria ler todas as chaves de uma seção em um arquivo ".ini" e usa-los como string.

Ex:

```
[ITENS]
pedido1 = 3552
pedido2 = 2208
pedido3 = 2066
pedido4 = 5787
pedido5 = 2966
pedido6 = 8889
```

Retorno:
 String array[] = [pedido1, pedido2, pedido3, pedido4, pedido5, pedido6]

Eu já uso o GetPrivateProfileStringA da "windows.h" para pegar um valor de uma chave, mas tive problemas para pegar o nome de todas as chaves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mesma coisa da [resposta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/368901/138506) mas jogando em um std::vector:

```
std::vector<std::string> chaves;
for(const char *resultado = lista; strlen(resultado); resultado += strlen(resultado) + 1)
    chaves.push_back(std::string(resultado, (int)(strchr(resultado, '=') - resultado)));
```

Comment: Eu sou meio que iniciante. Eu tentei assim. Tenho dificuldades de converter variaveis. Na linguagem que eu usava era tudo meio que automatica

string sistema = "pedido1 = 3552\0pedido2 = 2208\0pedido3 = 2066\0\0";

std::vector<std::string> chaves;
for(const char *resultado = sistema; strlen(resultado); resultado += strlen(resultado) + 1)
    chaves.push_back(std::string(resultado, (int)(strchr(resultado, '=') - resultado)));

Comment: Este é um exemplo, mas neste exemplo, use char*sistema = ...